# How to debug Node.js with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using the Google Chrome Developer Tools plugin for Eclipse to debug my Node.js server. This server uses Socket.io for the websocket connection between my web client and the server. The problem comes when I set a breakpoint in my server and start stepping through the code. The client soon decides the server isn't there anymore because there's no longer a heartbeat or any communication, so it disconnects. Meanwhile, as I'm stepping through, my code tries to do something with the socket and then it dies since the socket is now shutdown. It makes it a bit tricky trying to debug like this.

So the question is, how can I debug a server like this with an open websocket connection and not close the connection? I don't know that there's a good solution, but I thought I'd put it out there and see if anyone has a genius idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing more research I discovered a couple different projects that looked hopeful, namely 'node-inspector' and 'node-codein'. However, node-inspector doesn't work with the latest versions of node, and node-codein has a lot of bugs. Also, neither is really maintained and they both only work with Chrome. So, I wrote my own solution, called [Node Monkey](https://github.com/jwarkentin/node-monkey), which is really simple to use and it works with Firefox or Chrome. It simply captures things logged to the console in your Node app and redirects that output to the browser console. You can install it by running:

```
npm install node-monkey
```

Comment: Nice job Justin. Looking forward to giving it a whirl.

Answer (score 6):

Even if it sounds a littly nasty and stone-aged, but in this cases (actually debugging a client->server environment) I regulary use standard outputs on the server-side, just like `console.log()` and `console.debug`.

If you need to debug your client-side script, you *could* do just the same, if you don't want to lose the server connection. I actually don't see any other way around it beside you re-configure *socket.IO*'s heartbeat timeouts fundamentally higher.

Comment: That's what I normally do, but I was stuck in a situation where dumping out to the console wasn't realistic because of the data I needed to inspect. It would scroll far beyond the limit of my console buffer and doesn't allow inspection of deeply nested objects. If I could dump the debug data out to a browser somehow and use Firebug or the Chrome console then I could inspect objects the way I need.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is ages later, but another option I found that ended up being perfect for a quick socket.io sanity check is [socket-io-tester](https://github.com/AppSaloon/socket.io-tester).

I mention it here since this answer was the first result on google and it took me a little more digging to find the tool.

Comment: That's useful for testing Socket.IO but not so much for app debugging. If you're trying to do a `console.log()` for debugging purposes node-monkey actually captures that and sends it to the browser console for inspection. From what I can tell, with socket-io-tester you'd still have to handle that manually since it's not purpose-built for it. That said, it looks like a very useful app I'll probably end up using in the future, so thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

**for this you can follow official documentation of socket.io**

> https://socket.io/docs/v3/logging-and-debugging/index.html

In my case, I did this in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
 "start": "DEBUG=engine,socket.io* nodemon src/server.js"},
```

I hope it will help you or feel free to ask me in case you have any doubt

Comment: i am getting
DEBUG=engine,socket.io* node app

'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command